# Pandas to_csv creating file while running as script but not creating file while running as airflow dag

Tags: python, flask, airflow

I have a below script which uses pandas `to_csv` to create a csv

**dict_to_csv.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
import os

def create_test_csv():
    sample_dict = {
        'test1': (1, 2001),
        'test2': (2, 3001),
        'test3': (3, 4001)
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict, orient="index")
    root_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
    path_to_create = os.path.join(root_path, "testing.csv")
    print(f"creating csv in path: {path_to_create}")
    df.to_csv(path_to_create)
    print(f"created csv in path: {path_to_create}")

create_test_csv()
```

If I run this as a script. It creates file as expected

But if I run it as airflow dag inside a docker container by importing it, it is not creating a file, nor it is giving any error

**csv_test_dag.py**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import logging
import pandas as pd

from scripts.dict_to_csv import create_test_csv


def create_csv(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        create_test_csv()

        return "created csv"

    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(e)

with DAG(

        dag_id="csv_test_dag",
        schedule_interval="*/10 * * * *",
        default_args={
            "owner": "airflow",
            "retry": 1,
            "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
            "start_date": datetime(2022, 4, 1),
        },
        catchup=False,
    ) as f:

    create_csv = PythonOperator(
            task_id="create_csv",
            python_callable=create_csv
        )
```

change in **dict_to_csv.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
import os

def create_test_csv():
    sample_dict = {
        'test1': (1, 2001),
        'test2': (2, 3001),
        'test3': (3, 4001)
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict, orient="index")
    root_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
    path_to_create = os.path.join(root_path, "testing.csv")
    print(f"creating csv in path: {path_to_create}")
    df.to_csv(path_to_create)
    print(f"created csv in path: {path_to_create}")
```

In both the cases, script is running fine without any error and is printing **creating csv in path: path/to/create...** and **created csv in path: path/to/create...** before and after ***df.to_csv(path_to_create)*** respectively, only difference is while running as script, it is creating a file but with airflow dag it is not creating a file. I have checked for the inside the container and on host.

I am using below versions of airflow and pandas

```
pandas==1.1.5
airflow==2.2.0
```

How do I resolve this issue

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have defined a volume in Docker, binding your computer path to the Docker container path, the created CSV will be only available within the docker container.

If you enter into the container, the file will be there.

Comment: I have checked inside container as well. there is no file